# Create border between pages with UIScrollView

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode

I am trying to create a black border between views when users scroll pages I am using `UIPageControl` and `UIScrollView`, something like this pictures :
does anybody know how to do this !?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just set your scroll view's background to [UIColor black] and set image frames like this:

```
NSArray *images = ...//your array of UIImage
CGFloat blackSpaceWidth = 20;
for(int i=0; i<images.count; i++){
   UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:images[i]];
   imageView.frame = CGRectMake((self.view.frame.size.width + blackSpaceWidth) * i, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height);
   scrollView.addSubview(imageView);
}
```

If you are using pagination in your scroll view increase its frame width by blackSpaceWidth.

Comment: app crashes ! ..` Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIImageView _isDecompressing]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fb7c16c67e0`

Answer (score 0):

I guess it is pretty simple.All you need to do is left spacing between views in scrollview. Suppose you have set frame of first view like this -

`[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,320,self.view.frame.size.height)];`

for next view declare your frame for view like this -

```
[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,320+spacing,320,self.view.frame.size.height)];
```

and obviously set scrollview background color to black.

Comment: This code make stroke around view ! I just need to display the border when scrolling is happening

Comment: then set scrollview background black and when scrolling is happening distract this black stroke's width say 20 from width of views.Otherwise keep it same as view's width

Answer (score 0):

you can use CollectionView

1- make cell width 320 + 20px (border width) and cell height equal to screen height

2- set cell background with black color

3- add imageView constraints in this cell if you are using auto layout

4- implement CollectionView datasource